# SharePoint provider hosted app gives iframe warning "This content cannot be displayed in a frame;"

Tags: sharepoint-addin, iframe

SharePoint 2013 on-premises. My app has domain "myApp.com" and my sitecollection has the domain "mySitecollection.com". I use adfs authentication. I created a page on "mysitecollection.com". On this page I add the appart to a webpartzone. When I this page in IE I got the following error:

**This content cannot be displayed in a frame**

When I go to site contents and click on the app I resolve this issue. When I log out and log in I got this issue again.

I add this code to the masterpage of "mysitecollection.com":

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat=”server” />
```

And I have these logic in my SharePoint app mvc web project:

P3PHeaderFilterAttribute.cs:

```
public class P3PHeaderFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("p3p",
                "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");

            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

FilterConfig.cs:

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new P3PHeaderFilterAttribute());
        }
    }
```

global.ascx:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles); 

            // https://platinumdogs.me/2015/03/06/enable-iframing-in-a-sharepoint-provider-hosted-mvc-app/
            // allow cross domain framing: Disable the HTTP Header X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
            AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
        }
```

Why do I still have this iframe issue and how can I fix this? In chrome it is working fine.

App MVC Web project web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientId" value="0aeb5a99-dcc6-4208-9398-a4fc10272c6b" />
    <add key="ClientSigningCertificatePath" value="E:\Certs\S2S.pfx" />
    <add key="ClientSigningCertificatePassword" value="Password!@#$" />
    <add key="IssuerId" value="32b83da0-4ef5-4bd2-a664-4561f4a1a40c" />
    <add key="spsaml:ClaimProviderType" value="SAML" />
    <add key="spsaml:TrustedProviderName" value="MyCompany Provisioning" />
    <add key="spsaml:IdentityClaimType" value="SMTP" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!--Used by app for SharePoint-->
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="urn:sharepoint:myCompany:provisioning"/>
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="adfs.dev.com">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="44243b28d7b9c69027d8e9b780634cc31549bd21"/>
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://adfs.dev.com/adfs/services/trust"/>
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" reply="https://apps.myCompany.com" issuer="https://adfs.dev.com/adfs/ls/" realm="urn:sharepoint:myCompany:provisioning" requireHttps="true" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: {6A153F6B-DD14-4C55-AAE9-17FE7BBAB293}-->
```

Comment: Is that page hosted on your `myApp.com` or in the app web?

Comment: I am talking about a page on "mysitecollection.com". On that page I added a appart to a webpartzone.

Comment: _"I add this code to the masterpage"_ If you added `WebPartPages:AllowFraming` to your `mySitecollection.com` it will not take effect. You need to modify your app, not host web.

Comment: What do I need to modify in my app?

Comment: You have added `SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader `, normally that should help..

Comment: yes I know, but I still have this issue.

Comment: How do you track authentication inside your app (myApp.com)? Are you using cookies?

Comment: See comments below and updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause for such behavior is ADFS.

When you are not logged in into your `myApp.com` you redirected to ADFS authentication page. This page by default sets `x-frame-options:DENY` and it's not possible to change that (and not recommended since this is security setting).
Some additional info: [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/699337/how-can-the-x-frame-options-http-header-of-adfs-3-be-manipulated) [two](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad370ac6-ba70-470c-8966-022010663fa5/active-directory-federated-services-xframeoptions-deny?forum=Geneva)

I didn't find any relative information over internet about how you can change this default behavior. You can try, may you will be lucky.

I can suggest only workarounds:

- don't use ADFS auth in your `myApp.com` and use windows auth (you may lose SSO under some circumstances)
  OR
- for client web part "pages" disable authentication at all and rely on app-only security if you need to talk with SharePoint (of course if it's suitable for your requirements)
  OR
- use ADFS, but when user tries to open client web part "page", give a message "You need to authenticated, please click the link below", the link will open yours app page in a new window (not iframed, `target="_blank"`), or you can try to trigger javascript `window.open` from your client web part to open your page a new browser window, not iframed, after login process is done, listen for close window event and refresh app's part page
  OR
- don't use client web parts at all and instead provide some pre-configured script editor web parts, which will talk to SharePoint from javscript and to your web api via CORS

**UPD**
As per comments from @Ola below, it appears that the fix is actually rather simple - you need to add SharePoint domain, ADFS domain and your app domain under Trusted sites in IE. Note, that this solution works, if you are using `SharePointContextSaml` and configured your app properly for ADFS authentication. Consider this great writing by Wictor Wilen: [SharePoint 2013 with SAML Claims and Provider Hosted Apps](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-with-saml-claims-and-provider-hosted-apps)

Comment: Thank you for this information. You triggered me to check also the header of the ADFS login page (https://adfs.dev.com/adfs/ls?..................). There you see x-frame-options:DENY. When I open the app in a seperated browser tab I see the ADFS login page again but I was already logged in ADFS before when I entered the "mySitecollection.com". So this triggered me that the "adfs.dev.com" is in another zone than the "mySitecollection.com" and "myApp.com". I put al the 3 urls in the local intranet zone. And now it is working fine! Thank you Kai for the trigger.

Comment: That sounds strange for me that this solution works. How did you implement ADFS authentication in your app? In other words how do you in your app verify that user already authenticated?

Comment: I created in VS a new app project. In this app project I use the SharePoint ClientContext : ClientContext clientContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext.Current).CreateUserClientContextForSPHost();. See also updated post for the web.config of the app mvc website.

Comment: By default `SharePointContextProvider` doesn't support adfs. It's working most probably because you actually using windows authentication and not ADFS. In Visual Studio under MVC project properties make sure that Windows auth is disabled - [https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6P2w.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6P2w.png). If it's enabled (like I think in your case) then your approach with trusted sites will work, but not with adfs. Or you are actually using `SharePointContextSaml`

Comment: Hi Kai,
By default SharePointContextProvider doesn't support adfs. Can you justify?
I have same scenerio. it will be helpful. and also need alternate of "SharePointContextProvider "

Comment: @PrashantShah: you can look inside 'TokenHelper.cs', you will find lines `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` - this code uses current windows user and that works only if windows authentication is enabled. Besides there is an excellent post by Wictor Wilen describes how to configure your addin with saml (ADFS) - [SharePoint 2013 with SAML Claims and Provider Hosted Apps](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-with-saml-claims-and-provider-hosted-apps)

Comment: Hi Kai, Thank you so much for quick response. I am able to get context but my question is I am log in as spadmin@spdomain.com and APP user logged in as IISAppPool\SPAPP. How can i have same user in both context?

Comment: Which authentication you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50523/discussion-between-prashant-shah-and-kai).

Comment: Hi Prashant, we followed this adfs implementation tutorial and it works fine: https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/deploying-adfs3-for-sharepoint-2013-in-a-perimeter-network#.V_9xYemQqUn

Comment: Hi @Ola Thank You for your answer. I have followed same steps. But My Question is I login in to SharePoint as user SPDomain\Spadmin and while clicking on APP ClientContext giving  IISAppPool\SPAPP user.

Do you find same user in both context(SP Site and APP Site)? Also you can find question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203172/provider-hosted-app-with-adfs-created-by-issue/203591#203591